# how to unmarshall only the single nested element using javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling, javax.xml

I have a following sample xsd

```
 <annotation><appinfo>
<jaxb:schemaBindings>
    <jaxb:package name="com.myapp"/>
</jaxb:schemaBindings>
</appinfo></annotation>
<element name="user">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="roles" type="u:Roles" minOccurs="1"></element>
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="name" type="string"></attribute>
    </complexType>
</element>

<complexType name="Role">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="u:Role">
            <attribute name="name" type="string"></attribute>
            <attribute name="action" type="string"></attribute>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

I want to unmarshall only a Roles xml like the sample as follows

```
        JAXBContext c = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class, Roles.class, Role.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = c.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBElement ele = (JAXBElement) unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
    return (Roles) ele.getValue();
```

My input stream/xml is

```
<roles>
    <role name="admin" action="all"/>
    <role name="recep" action="select"/>
</roles>
```

The above code throws the following error

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.myapp.com/xsd/internal/myapp", local:"roles"). Expected elements are <{http://www.myapp.com/xsd/internal/myapp}User>
```

How to get my roles xml to be unmarshall?

Comment: Any comments is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the class you want to unmarshal, use the `unmarshal(Source source, Class<T> declaredType)` and likes.

So try `unmarshaller.unmarshall(source, Roles.class)` which would give you `JAXBElement<Roles>`. You can then `getValue()` from it to get an instance of `Roles`.

If you provide the class for unmarshalling, the root element name does not matter at all, JAXB does not neet to "know" it.

Comment: I'am exactly in the case I don't know the target class. Is there any option to perform this without knowing the target class ?